# NAND gate that outputs 0 when all inputs are 0

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm trying to work out a piece of binary logic and this is essentially what I am trying to achieve:

```
A B C | Output

0 0 0 | 0

0 0 1 | 1

0 1 1 | 1

0 1 0 | 1

1 0 0 | 1

0 1 1 | 1

1 0 1 | 1

1 1 0 | 1

1 1 1 | 0
```

I am attempting to implement this using logic gates and I have tried playing around with the NAND and NOT gates to somehow combine the two, but I am failing to get the exact logic that I am after. Any tips here would be very appreciated.

Comment: It is best to use a systematic ordering of the input values such as a binary count. I note that you have duplicated the '011' line, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the general case of this type of problem, read about [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and specifically [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (or its dual 'sum-of-products').
That said, this one is simple enough to do by inspection. Here's one implementation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffC3aI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the truth table you gave, we're looking for an output that is 0 only when A=B=C.

XOR1 compares A and B for equality, XOR2 compares B and C for equality; each of their outputs is 0 when their inputs are equal.

So we want Q to be 0 only when X=0 and Y=0.  An OR gate achieves that.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by writing the logic expressions for your truth table. Normally you'll write the logic equations for the input combinations where the output is 1, (sum of products) but in this case, since your system output has less 0s than 1s, we can write the expressions for the 0s instead and then invert the result. This is a slightly modified method for the writing the expression as products os sums.

So we have:

`Initial expression`

\$Output = \overline{\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + ABC}\$

`We break the inversion of the two terms by replacing the sum with a product`

\$Output = \overline{\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}} \cdot \overline{ABC}\$

`We break the inversion of the first term by replacing the products with sums`

\$Output = (\bar{\bar{A}}+\bar{\bar{B}}+\bar{\bar{C}}) \cdot \overline{ABC}\$

`We simplify the double inversions on the first term`

\$Output = (A+B+C) \cdot \overline{ABC}\$

This results in this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYMhgn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to do this as PoS instead of SoP.

\$(A + B + C)(\bar A + \bar B + \bar C)\$

\$ = (A + B + C)\overline{(ABC)}\$

So a 3-input OR, a 3-input NAND, and a 2-input AND.